# How to merge multiple column into one, make it looped but divided by row with duplicate id with PHP and OracleSQL?

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I've code but I cant make it like I want, the requirement is make the data I've to repeat the data owned by same id through just one column, although from real database it separated (different column), so this is the data I've

```
number  pay_status  card_status
021998877  UNPAID  ACTIVE
021998875  NULL  NOT ACTIVE
021998875  NULL  ACTIVE
```

And I want to change it like this:

```
number   others 
021998877  ACTIVE 
021998877  UNPAID  
021998876  NOT ACTIVE 
021998875  ACTIVE
```

Now I just can to get output like this:

```
021998877  ACTIVE UNPAID
```

and this is my code for the output

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)) {
        printf("<tr><td>%d</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n", $row['no'],
            $row['card_status'],$row['pay_status'] );
```

I'm using PHP and OracleSQL for the database. Please help, thank you

Comment: `021998876  NOT ACTIVE ` needs to be `021998875  NOT ACTIVE `? isn't it?

Comment: hmm.. sorry but it's not like that. i want the value from column 3++ placed in column 2 with repeated ID its not depend of the content from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you are saying, if the `card_status` is not NULL then print a second line.

In that case this would do it quite simply.

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)) {
    printf("<tr><td>%d</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n", 
                $row['no'],
                $row['pay_status'] );
    if ( $row['card_status'] != 'NULL' ) {
        printf("<tr><td>%d</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n", 
                $row['no'],
                $row['card_status'] );
    }
}
```

> You may need to amend the test for `NULL` depending on what that value actually is on the result set!

From your comment it counds like you have more than the 3 columns in the row than you mentioned initially.

To do this for multiple columns in the resultset you can loop over the columns in the resultset and  print the result over many rows in your output, converting NULL to the string `'NULL'`.

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_assoc($stid)) {
    foreach ( $row as $colname => $value) {
        if ( $colname == 'no' ) {
            continue;   // ignore the key field column
        }

        $value = $value == NULL ? 'NULL : $value

        printf("<tr><td>%d</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n", 
                    $row['no'],
                    $value );
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying that code for now, but would I ask if I want to make it check any columns not null, how I can? and if it was found null then give string "NULL" or just "<space>"?

Comment: So in reality you have more than 3 columns right? And all but the `$row['no']` could contain NULL Right??

Comment: Yes its absolutely right because not just card status contains null

Comment: Ok, I have amended my answer

Comment: yes , great it works perfectly, but i dont know how to make if was found null from one column then give string "NULL" or just "<space>" and export it to txt (if it is possible)

Comment: So you are now saying you want to see the columns with NULL in them in the printout? With the word NULL in that line?

Comment: Do you mean something like that? I amended my answer again